How do I dynamically change style for button in Maui?
I am wondering how do I dynamically change style for button.
What I expect is when I click first button the style should change to "ClickedButton" but for the second should be "DefaultButton", respectively when second button is clicked. These styles are defined in styles.xaml file.
I am tring something like this:
View:
<ContentView.Resources>
    <styleConverter:StyleConverter x:Key="StyleConverter" 
                                   DefaultStyle="{StaticResource DefaultButton}"
                                   ClickedStyle="{StaticResource ClickedButton}"/>
</ContentView.Resources>
<Grid RowDefinitions="19, 2, 42">
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Alarm state" Margin="2, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="4" WidthRequest="0"/>

    <Border 
        WidthRequest="180"
        Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource DefaultBorder}">
        <Grid
            ColumnDefinitions="58, 58, 58"
            x:DataType="viewModel:OverviewListVM"
        >
            <Border Style="{StaticResource LeftRoundedBorder}" >
                <Button Padding="0" Text="All" HeightRequest="38"
                        Style="{Binding IsButtonAllClicked, Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}}"
                        Command="{Binding ButtonAllClickedCommand}">
                    
                </Button>
            </Border>

            <Border Style="{StaticResource RightRoundedBorder}" Grid.Column="2" >
                <Button ImageSource="warning.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Style="{Binding IsButtonWarnClicked, Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}}"
                      Command="{Binding ButtonWarnClickedCommand}"
                >
                </Button>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>

Converter:
 public class StyleConverter : IValueConverter
 {
     public Style? DefaultStyle { get; set; }

     public Style? ClickedStyle { get; set; }
     public object? Convert(object? value, Type? targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo? culture)
     {
         return (bool)value! ? ClickedStyle : DefaultStyle;
     }

     public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
 }


ViewModel:
 [ObservableProperty]
 private bool isButtonWarnClicked = false;

 [ObservableProperty]
 private bool isButtonAllClicked = true;

 [RelayCommand]
 private void ButtonAllClicked()
 {
     ResetButtons();
     IsButtonAllClicked = true;
 }

 [RelayCommand]
 private void ButtonWarnClicked()
 {
     ResetButtons();
     IsButtonWarnClicked = true;
 }

 private void ResetButtons()
 {
     IsButtonAllClicked = false;
     IsButtonWarnClicked = false;
 }

Only style for the first button is set (IsButtonAllClicked = true), when I click to warn button the relaycommand is triggering but style doesn't change. How do I change style dynamically with MVVM pattern?
Edit1: (another approach according to @Jessie Zhang -MSFT, only view changed)
<Grid RowDefinitions="19, 2, 42">
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Alarm state" Style="{StaticResource TextBlue1}" Margin="2, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="4" WidthRequest="0"/>

    <Border 
        WidthRequest="180"
        Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource DefaultBorder}">
        <Grid
            ColumnDefinitions="58, 58, 58"
            x:DataType="viewModel:OverviewListVM"
        >
            <Border Style="{StaticResource LeftRoundedBorder}" >
                <Button Text="All" HeightRequest="38" Padding="0" Command="{Binding ButtonAllClickedCommand}">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsButtonAllClicked}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ClickedButton}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsButtonAllClicked}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource DefaultButton}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </Border>

            <Border Style="{StaticResource RightRoundedBorder}" Grid.Column="2" >
                <Button ImageSource="warning.png" Command="{Binding ButtonWarnClickedCommand}" >
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsButtonWarnClicked}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ClickedButton}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsButtonWarnClicked}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource DefaultButton}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>

But still nothing happens.
Edit2: (another approach, changed Button.Style to Button.Triggers)
new View
<Grid RowDefinitions="19, 2, 42">
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Alarm state" Style="{StaticResource TextBlue1}" Margin="2, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="4" WidthRequest="0"/>

    <Border 
        WidthRequest="180"
        Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource DefaultBorder}">
        <Grid
            ColumnDefinitions="58, 58, 58"
            x:DataType="viewModel:OverviewListVM"
        >
            <Border Style="{StaticResource LeftRoundedBorder}" >
                <Button Text="All" HeightRequest="38" Padding="0" Command="{Binding ButtonAllClickedCommand}">
                    <Button.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsButtonAllClicked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource ClickedButton}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsButtonAllClicked}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Button.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </Border>

            <Border Style="{StaticResource RightRoundedBorder}" Grid.Column="2" >
                <Button ImageSource="warning.png" Command="{Binding ButtonWarnClickedCommand}">
                    <Button.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsButtonWarnClicked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource ClickedButton}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsButtonWarnClicked}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Button.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>

Still nothing happens.

You can use  Triggers to achieve this.

I add Edit1 to post, but there still nothing happend when I clicked.

My error was as follows: public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged.
ViewModel extends ObservableObject and INotifyPropertyChanged,
when I remove INotifyPropertyChanged the user interface refreshes. So this works for me:
<Button ImageSource="warning.png" Command="{Binding ButtonWarnClickedCommand}">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsButtonWarnClicked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ClickedButton}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button"  Binding="{Binding IsButtonWarnClicked}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>

